# how to perfect a jumbotron image in my page

Tags: html, css

The image I selected is too big and does not fit the page vertically or horizontally. here is what I have:

```
<style>

.jumbotron {
height: 500px;
width: 100%;
}
.jumbo-container {
background-image: url('../img/challenge2.jpg');
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: cover;
width: 100%;
}
</style>

<body>
 <div class="jumbotron">
  <div class="jumbo-container">
  </div>
 </div>
</body>
```

link to the picture I want: http://fc09.deviantart.net/fs71/f/2010/347/0/2/life_challenges_by_eddieretelj-d34scch.jpg

Comment: Not completly sure what you're asking but i added height:100%; check fiddle; http://jsfiddle.net/mhussa19/r0pq2zra/

Comment: @Phreak the image is cutoff horizontally in your fiddle. How do I prevent that?

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: @che-azeh my picture is not fitting on the page. with the code I used above, the picture is being cutoff vertically. How do I fix that?

Comment: its fitting fine in the fiddle?

Comment: do you mean its being cut of horizontally?

Comment: @Phreak on the actual fiddle page, the image was cutoff horizontally. I included your fiddle code on my text editor and now the image is being cut off veritically. If it makes any difference, I also have normalize css on my project. (I'm a rookie)

Comment: Either the image scales or it gets cut off, I think you should decide on which of these two options you want and then try improving from there.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you might need to use this take a look at my fiddle `background-size: 100% auto;` http://jsfiddle.net/mhussa19/r0pq2zra/2/

```
.jumbotron {
height: 500px;
width: 100%;
}
.jumbo-container {
background-image: url(' http://fc09.deviantart.net/fs71/f/2010/347/0/2/life_challenges_by_eddieretelj-d34scch.jpg');
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: 100% auto;
width: 100%;
    height:100%;
}
```

Comment: the image is still being cutoff vertically :/

Answer (score 0):

```
background-image: url('../img/challenge2.jpg'); height:100%; width:100%;
```

should work